# how to get the caller stage from ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> in focus change listener

Tags: javafx, focus, stage, changelistener

I want to have a focus listener as a static variable that is passed throw static method, and its function is to close a stage when focus on that stage is lost.

i have the code:

Main class

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load(), 565, 551);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        Controller controller = loader.getController();
        primaryStage.show();
        controller.setStage1InitOwner();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Controller class

```
 public class Controller implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private AnchorPane anchorPane;

    // stage1 suppose to be a small dialogs
    private final Stage stage1 = new Stage();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        stage1.setScene(new Scene(new Pane(new Label("a Dialog")), 200, 200));

        // giving the listener to stage1 from static method
        stage1.focusedProperty().addListener(Prepare.getFocusListener());
        stage1.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
    }

    public void setStage1InitOwner() {
        stage1.initOwner(anchorPane.getScene().getWindow());
        stage1.show();
    }
}
```

Prepare class (static methods and variables inside)

```
  public class Prepare  {
    public static ChangeListener<Boolean> focusListener = new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observableValue, Boolean aBoolean, Boolean t1) {
            if (!t1) ;
            // get the stage from observableValue and close it when focus is lost.
        }
    };
    public static ChangeListener<Boolean> getFocusListener()
    {
        return focusListener;
    }
}
```

fxml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="anchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="551.0" prefWidth="565.0" style="-fx-background-color: #fffe00;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

now i want to get the caller stage from the ObservableValue inside the ChangeListener.
i tried to cast it to BooleanProperty and then use getBean()

```
 if (!t1) {
            BooleanProperty booleanProperty = (BooleanProperty) observableValue;
            Stage stage = (Stage) booleanProperty.getBean();
            stage.close();
        }
```

, but i got the following error:

```
    Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: class javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl cannot be cast to class javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty (javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl and javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty are in module javafx.base of loader 'app')
    at sample.Prepare$1.changed(Prepare.java:13)
    at sample.Prepare$1.changed(Prepare.java:9)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:360)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:80)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.java:78)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.java:103)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:111)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window.setFocused(Window.java:678)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window$1.setFocused(Window.java:150)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.stage.WindowHelper.setFocused(WindowHelper.java:112)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.stage.WindowPeerListener.changedFocused(WindowPeerListener.java:64)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.run(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:126)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.run(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:40)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.lambda$handleWindowEvent$4(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:178)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.handleWindowEvent(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:176)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.Window.handleWindowEvent(Window.java:1336)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.Window.notifyFocus(Window.java:1315)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: class javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl cannot be cast to class javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty (javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl and javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty are in module javafx.base of loader 'app')
    at sample.Prepare$1.changed(Prepare.java:13)
    at sample.Prepare$1.changed(Prepare.java:9)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:360)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:80)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.java:78)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.java:103)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:111)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window.setFocused(Window.java:678)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window$1.setFocused(Window.java:150)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.stage.WindowHelper.setFocused(WindowHelper.java:112)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.stage.WindowPeerListener.changedFocused(WindowPeerListener.java:64)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.run(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:126)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.run(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:40)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.lambda$handleWindowEvent$4(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:178)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.handleWindowEvent(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:176)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.Window.handleWindowEvent(Window.java:1336)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.Window.notifyFocus(Window.java:1315)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinWindow._close(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.Window.close(Window.java:352)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinWindow.close(WinWindow.java:316)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.WindowStage.lambda$close$4(WindowStage.java:824)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:442)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.WindowStage.close(WindowStage.java:817)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window$12.invalidated(Window.java:1157)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Window.java:1190)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window.hide(Window.java:1215)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.stage.WindowCloseRequestHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(WindowCloseRequestHandler.java:45)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.stage.WindowPeerListener.closing(WindowPeerListener.java:93)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.run(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:147)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.run(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:40)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.lambda$handleWindowEvent$4(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:178)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.handleWindowEvent(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:176)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.Window.handleWindowEvent(Window.java:1336)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.Window.notifyClose(Window.java:1241)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

so what's the problem, and what is the best way to get the stage.

Big Thanks in advance for StackOverflow team.

Comment: the error message tells you _exactly_ what's wrong: focusedProperty is a ReadOnlyProperty :)

Comment: You don’t need static anything.  In a lambda attached to a focus listener for the stage, you could close the stage if focus is lost. `stage.focusedProperty().addListener((o, wasFocused, isFocused) -> if (!isFocused) stage.close());`.

Comment: jewelsea i would like to have static listener to give it directly to any stage i want, instead of re-coding it, so i think it's a good idea.

Comment: wondering what _exactly_ you don't understand: we are trying a typecast to access a certain api (the bean), that didn't work out and threw a ClassCastException which is very precise (maybe overly so ;) As we know the property we are passing in (it's stage.focusedProperty()), you look up the return type of that method in the api doc (ReadOnlyBooleanProperty - looks similar to the one in the error method, doesn't it :), change our cast from BooleanProperty to ReadOnlyBooleanProperty and all is well. All quite straightforware, so were is the problem?

Comment: asides: a) I agree with @jewelsea that the approach looks convoluted - there might be reasons in production, but that's rather irrelevant here: a simple [mcve] would contain just a plain application showing an empty stage which has a changeListener to its focusedProperty, trying to access the stage from the sender via a type-cast to the sender b) as a design note: utility classes with static support methods are fine, but better let them do the work completely: implement something  closeOnFocusLost(Stage) which internally adds a private listener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error tells you what's wrong:

> ```
> java.lang.ClassCastException: class javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl cannot be cast to class javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty (javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl and javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty are in module javafx.base of loader 'app')
> ```

You're trying to cast a `ReadOnlyBooleanProperty` instance to a `BooleanProperty`, which obviously is not possible. But you don't actually need to deal with such "narrow" implementations. All you care about is getting the "bean", and that only requires the type to be a [`ReadOnlyProperty<?>`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/18/javafx.base/javafx/beans/property/ReadOnlyProperty.html) (which is the top of the property class hierarchy).

```java
ChangeListener<Boolean> listener = (obs, wasFocused, isFocused) -> {
  if (!isFocused) {
    var property = (ReadOnlyProperty<?>) obs;
    var stage = (Stage) property.getBean();
    stage.close();
  }
};
```

However, you shouldn't need to deal with casting at all. If your goal is to simply avoid code duplication, then just create a utility method that accepts a `Stage` and adds a listener to its `focused` property.

For example:

```java
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public final class CloseOnFocusLost {

  private static final Object KEY = new Object();

  public static void installListener(Stage stage) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    var listener = (ChangeListener<Boolean>) stage.getProperties().get(KEY);
    if (listener == null) {
      listener = (obs, wasFocused, isFocused) -> {
        if (!isFocused) {
          stage.close();
        }
      };
      stage.getProperties().put(KEY, listener);
      stage.focusedProperty().addListener(listener):
    }
  }

  public static void uninstallListener(Stage stage) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    var listener = (ChangeListener<Boolean>) stage.getProperties().remove(KEY);
    if (listener != null) {
      stage.focusedProperty().removeListener(listener):
    }
  }

  // prevent instantiation of utility class
  private CloseOnFocusLost() {}
}
```

The above has a few advantages over your code:

- It is more type-safe.

  - Your code is vulnerable to a *second* `ClassCastException` because the listener could be added to a property which does not belong to a `Stage`.
- You don't have to deal with casting because you have direct access to the `Stage` instance.
- It has safeguards to prevent adding more than one listener to the same `focused` property.

If you don't care about the last point, and don't ever need to remove the listener, then you can simplify the code to the following:

```java
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public final class CloseOnFocusLost {

  public static void installListener(Stage stage) {
    stage.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, wasFocused, isFocused) -> {
      if (!isFocused) {
        stage.close();
      }
    });
  }

  // prevent instantiation of utility class
  private CloseOnFocusLost() {}
}
```

In either case, you'd add your close-on-focus-lost listener with:

```java
CloseOnFocusLost.installListener(theStageInstance);
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple executable application that demonstrates some of the techniques from [Slaw's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72817956/1155209), plus one or two more.  I won't add any additional explanation on these techniques as that is already covered well in Slaw's answer.

Only the last option in this example demonstrates programmatically ensuring that the listener is not added to the same stage more than once.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class StageClosureApp extends Application {
    private static final ChangeListener<Boolean> CLOSE_ON_FOCUS_LOSS_USING_BEAN_LISTENER =
            (o, wasFocused, isFocused) -> {
                if (!isFocused) ((Stage) ((ReadOnlyProperty<?>) o).getBean()).close();
            };

    private static ChangeListener<Boolean> closeOnFocusLossListener(Stage stage) {
        return (o, wasFocused, isFocused) -> {
            if (!isFocused) stage.close();
        };
    }

    private static void closeOnFocusLoss(Stage stage) {
        stage.focusedProperty().removeListener(CLOSE_ON_FOCUS_LOSS_USING_BEAN_LISTENER);
        stage.focusedProperty().addListener(CLOSE_ON_FOCUS_LOSS_USING_BEAN_LISTENER);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        // all options perform the same function (close the stage on losing focus).
        // when testing, only enable one option, commenting the others out.

        // option 1: use a closure to reference the stage in a lambda function defined inline.
        stage.focusedProperty().addListener((o, wasFocused, isFocused) -> {
            if (!isFocused) stage.close();
        });

        // option 2: pass the stage instance to a static listener generation function.
        stage.focusedProperty().addListener(closeOnFocusLossListener(stage));

        // option 3: get the stage from the bean in an inline lambda function.
        stage.focusedProperty().addListener((o, wasFocused, isFocused) -> {
            if (!isFocused) ((Stage) ((ReadOnlyProperty<?>) o).getBean()).close();
        });

        // option 4: use a single instance static change listener that get the stage from the bean.
        stage.focusedProperty().addListener(CLOSE_ON_FOCUS_LOSS_USING_BEAN_LISTENER);

        // option 5: update stage to add a focus loss listener when it is not focused (can safely be called multiple time for a stage)
        closeOnFocusLoss(stage);
            
        stage.setScene(new Scene(new Label("hello, world")));
        stage.show();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

If the stage losing focus is the only stage displayed in the application (as it is in these test cases), then, by default, the application will automatically shut down, according to the [application lifecycle](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html), as soon as focus on the stage is lost.

I'm not sure that this example adds much to Slaw's answer, but it might be useful, so I'll keep the post for now.